# Check if something is in a list and group and check if the password input is its following line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I want it to read from this file to check if the inputted username and password are present in the textfile list but I need that the password is being checked on the next line following the line on which username was found.

```
file = open("usernamepasswordfile2.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
username1 = input("Please enter your username: ")
password1 = input("Enter password: ")

if username1 in lines[0] or lines[0:900]:
    print("access granted")
else:
    print("access denied")
```

The contents of `usernamepasswordfile2.txt`:

```
zkhan
3J1R7r
tsd
f9kYrD
zkay
JYyNdC
hdend
mYR2OC
fkhan
JeL6u5
```

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a dictionary (read [the docs](https://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php)) where the keys are the usernames and the values are the passwords? Basically, a map of entries `username --> password`? Sounds good? Ok, here's how we do that:

It seems that your `usernamepasswordfile2.txt` password file has the following structure:

Odd (1, 3, 5...) lines contain your usernames, and even (2, 4, 6) lines contain the passwords, right? (the password line contains the password for the user in the line right above it)

You can take advantage of the fact that a `.readline()` will advance the file's offset to the beginning of the next line, so you can combine the iteration over the file (`for line in f`, which if you don't do anything... erm... special... gives you a line by line iterator over the file's contents) with the manual `readline()` inside the loop to effectively read odd lines (a.k.a usernames) in `for line in f` and the even lines in the `password = f.readline().strip()` below:

```
import pprint

users_passwords = dict()  # Better user_passwords = {}, but let's be explicit

f = open("usernamepasswordfile2.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    user = line.strip()
    print("This is the line I read: %s, this is the stripped version: %s" %
          (repr(line), line.strip()))
    password = f.readline().strip()
    print("Read user=%s, password=%s" % (user, password))
    users_passwords[user] = password

f.close()  # Yep, we have already loaded the contents
           # in the `user_passwords` dict, so let's 
           # close it (we're not gonna need it anymore)

print("Fetched:\n%s" % pprint.pformat(users_passwords))
print("The usernames are the users_passwords keys:\n%s" %
      pprint.pformat(users_passwords.keys()))
print("For instance, what is the password for username %s? %s"
      % ('zkhan', users_passwords['zkhan']))

username1 = input("Please enter your username: ")
if username1 in users_passwords.keys():
    print("access granted")
else:
    print("access denied")
```

Ok, so what's happening here?

When you open a file and do `for whatever in my_file:`, you will loop over the file's contents storing in `whatever` the *lines* contained the file. However, when you do `readline` within the `for` loop, you are effectively advancing one line. Think of it as:

First iteration:

`for line in f` --> Reads the 1st line in file `f` (and gets ready to read the next line).
Ok, this is a username (first line of the file).
Within that `for`, you do a `f.readline()` --> Reads (and advances one line)
the second line. This is a password (the password of the user you had in the first line which, as of now, is stored in `line`)

Second iteration:

`for line in f` --> Reads the 3rd line of the file (because `f.readline()` DID advance one line, remember?). That means `line` contains the second username.
Within the `for`, you do a `f.readline()` --> That returns the 4th line of the file, meaning: the password of the user that you have in `line` (second user in the file)

So you have something like this:

```
for line in f:   # Lines 1   3   5   ...
    #                     \   \   \
    f.readline() # Lines   2   4   6 ...
```

Lather, rinse and repeat as needed (as needed... well... until you have read the whole file)

And what is that... [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) thing? Well, when you do read a line from a file, the ending character (the newline: `\n`) will also be returned on each line. But you don't want that character, right? Since the newline is a white space character, you can get the stripped version of your line.

Since you are probably using this for learning purposes, I suggest you put a lot of `print` statements around, so you can follow exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

to

```
lines = file.read()
```

since `readlines()` have "\n" on each entry

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is the possibility of a false positive on a partial match, empty string, or newline

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` keeps the line endings, use e.g. `str.strip()` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the newline characters `\n` at the end of each line are being preserved by `readlines`.  So if your username is `'apple'`, it's not in the list `['apple\n', 'boy\n', ...]`.
You can fix this by stripping the whitespace from each of the read in lines with

```
with open("usernamepasswordfile2.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")

lines = file.readlines()

username = "heyyy"
passw = "heyyyy"

for i in range(len(lines)):
   lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')

for i in range(0,len(lines),2):
   if username == lines[i]:
      if passw == lines[i+1]:
          print("acces")
```

- you open the file and get all the data from it
- then you strip all the \n of the lines
- and then you check the data (with the range function in the for loop you can set the start stop and difference between each number in the sequence.)